# Prevent header background image going to narrow on larger viewports

Tags: css

I have a status menu as a header on certain pages on my site which works fine on narrower viewports but on larger ones the background image is stretched too wide and becomes too narrow so the status menu dissapears into the white body.

How can I stop the background image from going too narrow when the viewports are made wider?
Trying a min-height in css didn't seem to solve the issue for some reason.

with the html:

```
<header class="banner-header bg-light">
</header
```

and the css

```
.banner-header {
  width: 100%;
  background: url("../images/navbar-header.svg") no-repeat center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 180px; }
```

Working fine on smaller viewports
[image]

Goes to narrow on larger viewports
[image]

background image without status menu

[image]

Comment: Awesome... did you have a **question**? If so, please *edit* your post to **clearly** explain the problem you are having, and provide your **existing code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Update to clarify, thanks.

Comment: Try to add a `height: auto` so the image resizes proportionally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to control `background-size` manually on larger screens with `@media`

More info on `@media` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

More info on `background-size` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

For example:

```
.banner-header {
  width: 100%;
  background: url("../images/navbar-header.svg") no-repeat center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 180px;
}
@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .banner-header {
    background-size: 1600px 300px;
  }
}
```

`1600px` is the **width** and `300px` is the **height**. Those are placeholder values, pick what best suits your needs.

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks that didn't quite work but changing background-size to `height: 20vh;` inside the media query you suggested worked well.